# GPGPU CUDA memory usage statistics at runtime

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, memory-profiling

How do I access and output memory statistics (used memory, available memory) from all types of memory at runtime in CUDA C++?

Global memory, Texture memory, Shared memory, Local memory, Registers, (Constant memory?)

Bonus question: Could you point me to documentation on how to do it with the Windows CUDA profiler tool? Is memory profiling supported on all cards, or is it just some specific models that can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a runtime check of overall memory usage on the device, use the [cudaMemGetInfo](http://group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g376b97f5ab20321ca46f7cfa9511b978) API. Note that there is no such thing as dedicated texture memory on NVIDIA devices. Textures are stored in global memory and there is no way to separately account for them using any of the CUDA APIs that I am aware of. You can also programmatically inquire about the size of runtime components which consume global memory (runtime heap, printf buffer, stack) using the [cudaDeviceGetLimit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g720e159aeb125910c22aa20fe9611ec2) API.

Constant memory is statically assigned at compile time, and you can get the constant memory usage for a particular translation unit via [compile time switches](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#printing-code-generation-statistics).

There is no way of that I am aware of to check SM level resource usage (registers, shared memory, local memory) dynamically at runtime. You can query the per thread and per block resource requirements of a particular kernel function at runtime using the [cudaFuncGetAttributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g19b1696533069c03f646e2ce2beacc00) API.

The Visual profiler can show the same information collected at runtime in its [detail view](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#details-view). I am not a big user of the visual profiler, so I am not sure about whether it collects device level memory usage dynamically during a run. I certainly don't recall seeing anything like that, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into the resources you provided in your answer ASAP!